# How to handle empty AliasSeq?

Tags: templates, d, template-meta-programming

I'd like to transform a qualified name stored in a single `string` to `AliasSeq`. 
Here is my attempt:

```d
template QName(string qname_str) {
  static if (qname_str.empty) {
    import std.meta : AliasSeq;
    alias QName = AliasSeq!();
  } else {
    import std.meta : aliasSeqOf;
    alias QName = aliasSeqOf!(qname_str.split("."));
  }
}

unittest {
  // OK:
  static assert(QName!"com.example"[0..$-1] == QName!"com");

  // Error: incompatible types for ((tuple()) == (())): cannot use '==' with types
  static assert(QName!"com"[0..$-1] == QName!"");
}
```

Notice the error for the comparison with the empty qualified name. I tried various attempts so the left hand side has the same type as right hand side, and I also tried comparing them with `is`, but I got error in all cases. Any suggestions how to handle empty `AliasSeq`-s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is fine, but for comparison you need a [helper struct](https://forum.dlang.org/post/sulxqtfprmkeekjatqup@forum.dlang.org) and `is`:

```d
unittest {
  struct S(A...) {}
  static assert(is(S!(QName!"com.example"[0..$-1]) == S!(QName!"com")));
  static assert(is(S!(QName!"com.example", QName!"mail") == S!(QName!"com.example.mail")));
  static assert(is(S!(QName!"com"[0..$-1]) == S!(QName!"")));
}
```